# gcc can't see SDL

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw32

I'm trying to compile [this code](https://github.com/cyxx/rawgl) with MinGW, but I get this error, although I have SDL2 installed:

[image: Error]

The Makefile looks like this:

```
SDL_CFLAGS = `sdl2-config --cflags`
SDL_LIBS = `sdl2-config --libs` -lSDL2_mixer -lGL

DEFINES = -DBYPASS_PROTECTION

CXXFLAGS := -g -O -MMD -Wall $(SDL_CFLAGS) $(DEFINES)

SRCS = aifcplayer.cpp bitmap.cpp file.cpp engine.cpp graphics_gl.cpp graphics_soft.cpp \
    script.cpp mixer.cpp pak.cpp resource.cpp resource_nth.cpp resource_win31.cpp \
    resource_3do.cpp systemstub_sdl.cpp sfxplayer.cpp staticres.cpp unpack.cpp \
    util.cpp video.cpp main.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
DEPS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)

rawgl: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(SDL_LIBS) -lz

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

-include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: [Lesson 0: MinGW (Setting Up SDL)](http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-mingw).

Comment: Yes, I am sure it's installed. I even tried copying `SDL.h` into the code's directory, just to test, and I still got this error

Comment: From the linked lesson: `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`

Comment: @GeorgeHovhannisian Where did you install it? What is the path to SDL.h in your system? Run `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` and tell the output.

Comment: @HO1 `C:\MinGW\include\SDL2C:\MinGW\include\SDL2`

I'll try @Elliott's advice now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC doesn't know and see what you want if you don't tell it correctly. Installation is one thing, and providing the path to the`INCLUDE` and `LIB` directory is another thing.

You are running your code in Microsoft Windows command prompt, so using backticks won't work. In bash, it is used to get the output of one command and put it in place, so you have to run it manually. Run `sdl2-config --cflags` and `sdl2-config --libs` manually and replace them with the output in your makefile.

This is a sample Makefile for you, according to the path you have installed SDL:

```
SDL_CFLAGS = -I C:/MinGW/include/SDL2
SDL_LIBS = -L C:/MinGW/lib -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -lGL

DEFINES = -DBYPASS_PROTECTION

CXXFLAGS := -g -O -MMD -Wall $(SDL_CFLAGS) $(DEFINES)

SRCS = aifcplayer.cpp bitmap.cpp file.cpp engine.cpp graphics_gl.cpp graphics_soft.cpp \
    script.cpp mixer.cpp pak.cpp resource.cpp resource_nth.cpp resource_win31.cpp \
    resource_3do.cpp systemstub_sdl.cpp sfxplayer.cpp staticres.cpp unpack.cpp \
    util.cpp video.cpp main.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
DEPS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)

rawgl: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(SDL_LIBS) -lz

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

-include $(DEPS)
```

Otherwise, you can use bash for Windows to have all the great features of bash in Windows without any problem.

Comment: "use bash for Windows". Could you, please, expand on that topic a little bit or provide a link? I'm not familliar with that (or c++ coding in general) at all, to be honest.

Comment: @GeorgeHovhannisian Ok, I'll do that. But first check the Makefile and see if it works.

Comment: `Makefile:21: *** missing separator.  Stop.` Guess just a copy error, copied the line back from original. And then I get: `make: *** No rule to make target `/MinGW/lib', needed by `aifcplayer.o'.  Stop.`

Comment: Please copy the code again. There was a typo in it. Essentially, I replaced the output from `sdl2-config --cflags` and `sdl2-config --libs` in the place of them. That's all.

Comment: @GeorgeHovhannisian How did you install GCC and SDL? I want to create the exact same environment that you have.

Comment: It came with MinGW. Then I installed SDL2 manually (extracted from the archive)

Comment: OK, OK, my bad. It should be`-I C:/MinGW/include/SDL2` (space after `-I`)